# Stateless Functional Component (SFC) in React not responding to props from Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router-v4

I've got an `SFC` that's not reflecting the changes in the `Redux` store.  The reducer gets hit on a *onClick* event, but the `SFC` doesn't update.  Please don't assume that I know anything.  I'm still rookie with the `React` stack and am probably making a silly mistake.  I'm connected to the store, so why doesn't the component update?  I thought the props will be passed-in.

**SFC**

```
const Dogs = props => (
  <div>
    <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => props.dispatch(fetchDog())}>
      Show Dog
    </Button>
    {props.loading ? ( // <<< PROPS ARE ALWAYS UNDEFINED
      <p>Loading...</p>
    ) : props.error ? (
      <p>Error, try again</p>
    ) : (
      <p>
        <img src={props.url} />
      </p>
    )}
  </div>
);

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  url: state.url,
  loading: state.loading,
  error: state.error
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Dogs);
```

**Reducer**

```
import {
  REQUESTED_DOG,
  REQUESTED_DOG_SUCCEEDED,
  REQUESTED_DOG_FAILED
} from "../actions/index";

// Reducer
const initialState = {
  url: "",
  loading: false,
  error: false
};
const dog = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REQUESTED_DOG:
      return {
        url: "",
        loading: true,
        error: false
      };
    case REQUESTED_DOG_SUCCEEDED: // <<< WORKS AS INTENDED!
      return {
        url: action.url,
        loading: false,
        error: false
      };
    case REQUESTED_DOG_FAILED:
      return {
        url: "",
        loading: false,
        error: true
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default dog;
```

**Routing/links**

```
const Root = ({ store }) => (
  <Provider store={store}>
   ...
    <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
              <Route exact path="/dogs" component={Dogs} />
              {/* <Route
                path="/dogs"
                render={props => (
                  <Dogs
                    url={props.url}
                    error={props.error}
                    loading={props.loading}
                    {...props}
                  />
                )}
              /> */}
```

**Store**

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from "redux";
import { createLogger } from "redux-logger";
import rootReducer from "../reducers";
import DevTools from "../containers/DevTools";
import createSagaMiddleware from "redux-saga";
import { watchFetchDog } from "../sagas/dogSaga";

const logger = createLogger({
  duration: true
});

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();

const configureStore = preloadedState => {
  const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    preloadedState,
    compose(
      applyMiddleware(sagaMiddleware, logger), // logger must be the last middleware in chain
      DevTools.instrument()
    )
  );

  sagaMiddleware.run(watchFetchDog);

  if (module.hot) {
    // Enable Webpack hot module replacement for reducers
    module.hot.accept("../reducers", () => {
      store.replaceReducer(rootReducer);
    });
  }
  return store;
};

export default configureStore;
```

**Root Reducer**

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import agents from "./agents";
import visibilityFilter from "./visibilityFilter";
import theme from "./theme";
import dog from "../reducers/dog";

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  agents,
  visibilityFilter,
  theme,
  dog
});

export default rootReducer;
```

Comment: hmm the code you posted looks fine to me. is your application wrapped in redux's `Provider` component with the correct `store` passed to it?

Comment: Can we see your store config?

Comment: are you using `combineReducers` ? maybe you should log `state` in your `mapStateToProps` function.. maybe it's `state.dogs.url`

Comment: @devserkan...I added the store config

Comment: what is `rootReducer` look like?

Comment: So, you have a `rootReducer` then you are combining reducers. You should use the state name how you use there.

Comment: @devserkan...added root reducer

Comment: yup.. then @devserkan's answer is correct. in your mapstate function.. how can it know which reducer to get values from if you don't specify it by name?

Comment: @azium...it's all part of the learing process, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably using your `mapStateToProps` function wrong. You most likly have a dog state in your global one. So, it must be something like that:

```
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  url: state.dog.url,
  loading: state.dog.loading,
  error: state.dog.error
});
```

**Update after comments**

Yes, this is a fine and standard way of opening your state or states to your component. Since there is no single state in your store, you should specifically use the state you want here.

Right now you have a global `state` in your store and there are multiple states which you are combining like `dog`, etc in this global `state`

Comment: Okay, this works.  Is it a good way to do this?  I want to learn correctly.

Comment: Yes, it is the right way of doing this. I've also updated my answer.

Comment: So there's a global state as well as domain specific ones.

Comment: Yes. When I say globally I mean the top state object itself since you are combining other ones into one. Maybe the word "globally" is not so right here, `top` state? You can create your store with one reducer. If you do so, you will have one state.